# CountDownTimer variable

Tags: java, android, timer, countdown, flashlight

I have a major problem about changing the value from a constructor

This is an app for flashlights. It will connect to a site to check the interval value (ex. 500 ms) and it will store it to an variable named `frum_timer` every 2 seconds.

Here's a object for that.
(also it will update a boolean if there's a new value)

```
FlashActivity = new CountDownTimer(40000, frum_timer) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        stats_of_run = true;
        if (bool) {
            final_form.setText("\\Flash ON//");
            // CAMERA INSTRUCTIONS FOR OPENING FLASH
            bool = false;
            frumtimer_stats.setText("Speed:" + frum_timer);
        } else {
            stats_of_run = true;
            final_form.setText("->Flash OFF-<");
            // CAMERA INSTRUCTIONS FOR CLOSING FLASH
            bool = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }

}.start();
```

I made another `CountDownTimer` object with a refresh rate of 200 seconds to make sure the `frum_timer` from `FlashActivity` object will take change.

and using this

```
frumtimer_stats.setText("Speed:" + frum_timer);
```

in **FlashActivity** for displaying the variable.

However, after the variable `frum_timer` is changed, the `FlashLight` keep going again and again at the same old speed even if a made an `FlashActivity.cancel()` followed by `FlashActivity.start()`

Can someone give me some help?

Full link of code: 
https://mycodestock.com/public/snippet/14395

Summary:
1.You start the app.
2. Refresh countdown starts in 2 sec
3. When there is a **frum_timer** the FlashActivity will start. After 2 sec, if there is another value stored on frum_timer, the actual FlashActivity will be canceled and will start a new one. 
4.The problem is the new FlashActivity  start but with the **old** frum_timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
 public void startProgress(View view) {
        // do something long
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
              final int value = i;
               doFakeWork();


              progress.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 // text.setText("Updating");
                    progress.setMax(20);
                  progress.setProgress(value);
                }
              });
            }
          }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
      }


  private void doFakeWork() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(800);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```